# Sort a varchar2 array (apex_t_varchar2)

Tags: arrays, oracle, sorting, oracle-apex

I have to sort the output of a shuttle within an Oracle Apex Application.

I came up with this simple piece of pl/sql to do so, but I wondered if there's any way to it in a better fashion. Or at least, to not have to declare two variables to achieve the same result.

My PL/SQL:

```
DECLARE
    t       apex_t_varchar2;
    t_tmp   apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
    /* shuttle output is d:b:a:c*/
    t := apex_string.split(:MY_SHUTTLE, ':');
    
    FOR i IN (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE ( t ) ORDER BY 1) LOOP 
        apex_string.push(t_tmp, i.column_value);
    END LOOP;

    t := t_tmp;
    dbms_output.put_line(apex_string.join(t, ':'));
END;
```

output (which is correct) is:

```
a:b:c:d
```

Maybe there is a way to transform the SQL statement (`select ... from table(t)`) directly into an `apex_t_varchar2` arrray but I coulnd't manage to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to **SELECT** into the **apex_t_varchar2** array while sorting the array. The code below is an example how to do so.

```sql
DECLARE
    l_my_shuttle   VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'd:b:a:c';
    t_vals         apex_t_varchar2;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_my_shuttle);

      SELECT *
        BULK COLLECT INTO t_vals
        FROM TABLE (apex_string.split (l_my_shuttle, ':'))
    ORDER BY 1;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (apex_string.JOIN (t_vals, ':'));
END;
/
```

#### Output

```
d:b:a:c
a:b:c:d
```

Comment: Ok that's what I was looking for. I knew I missed something: I didn't know about BULK COLLECT. That's perfect, thanks

Comment: Rather than `SELECT * ... FROM TABLE( ... ) ORDER BY 1` you can use the `COLUMN_VALUE` pseudo-column and `SELECT COLUMN_VALUE ... FROM TABLE( ... ) ORDER BY COLUMN_VALUE`.